# How to run the embedded application

Tags: java-me

For example, I just developed an embedded SWT application which require CDC/FP1.0 j2se1.3 (I use the eclipse IDE), but how to test this application to see if it is can really run on embedded environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not many phones with a proper CDC stack have actually been produced as far as I know.

There was a port of the reference implementation of at least one CDC profile to UIQ 3.x that can be installed on a Sony-Ericsson P990 (and maybe Sony-Ericsson M600, W960 and Motorola Z8) phone.

Presumably, the Sun Java Toolkit for CDC contains an emulator that can run your application.

If none of that works, I would advise searching for what the companies on the two JSRs (JSR 36: Connected Device Configuration and JSR 46: Foundation Profile) expert groups did with CDC and FP.